# How to replace Null with empty string in Java insert prepared statement

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I have API response which I am using Java insert prepared statement to insert values in DB table.
Few column values coming in from API response is- `null`. I want to replace this null value with empty string in my table. Can someone help with the piece of code.

Code snippet:

```
PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
stmt.setDate(1, formatDate(obj.getString("term_dt")));
```

Comment: something like this: `v==null ? "" : v`

Comment: Does it make sense to use `""` when calling `formatDate`?  Possibly you should call [PreparedStatement's method `setNull`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setNull(int,%20int)) or provide appropriate default value?

Comment: Thanks Guys, I tried with if statement and it worked :if((obj.getString("term_dt"))!="null"){
    stmt.setDate(1, formatDate(obj.getString("term_dt")));
   }
   else{
    stmt.setString(1,"");
    }

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ternary operator to keep your code concise.

```java
PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
stmt.setDate(1, term_dt!=null ? formatDate(obj.getString("term_dt")) : "");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Objects.toString(obj.getString("term_dt"), "")`. It's a bit shorter than using a ternary operator.